# Decoding string of bytes back to bytes

Tags: json, python-3.x, byte

I need to save a byte string in a json file and get it back as a bytestring.

In order to be able to dump it into the json, I had to convert the bytes to a regular string. The problem I'm having is that once I read the json and try to encode the converted bytestring, the '\' are doubled, so the strings aren't the same.

How could you do it properly? :(

Input:
    salt = b'\xd5KS\xe4\x1b\xbd'

Output = b'\xd5KS\xe4\x1b\xbd'

Comment: I think the only sane way to serialize arbitrary binary data (which salts would be) in json is to encode them in something much safer, such as hexadecimal (very common for keys, salts, uuids, etc), or base64.

Comment: thank you! It worked encoding it as a hexadecimal :D